# Regex - Split string to group

Tags: regex

In regex how could like split the below string to different group ?

```
7000.401.581800.161E.000.0000.0000

group 1 = 7000

group 2 = 401

group 3 = 581800

group 4 = 000

group 5 = 0000

group 6 = 0000
```

Comment: [`(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\..*?\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)`](https://www.regex101.com/r/OHpljB/1)

Comment: This not really safte as the string can come with character

Comment: What language? It probably is something like `/(\d+)(?:\.|$)/g` [Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/UnAM9w/2)

Comment: this will do (\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)\.(\w+)

Comment: @user1902849 if you use \w+ you will also get the group that has a letter in it

Answer (score -2):

Split will split a string, i.e. divide it into substrings removing the pattern you provided, so for example if you split on "." :

```
foreach (string s in Regex.Split("7000.401.581800.161E.000.0000.0000", ".")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```